# What is the relation between the dog and animal classes in this Python code?

Tags: python

```
class animal(object):   
         pass

class dog(animal):
        def __init__(self):
            print "I got called"
```

I found this code in the book "Learn Python the hard way". I have questions about the relationship between `dog` and `animal`?

Are `dog` and `animal` both classes and does `dog` inherit something from `animal`?

Comment: Note: It's strongly suggested that you should capitalize the class names. See pep8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Comment: The relation is one of inheritance. `dog` inherits all the attributes and methods of `animal`, which is to say none at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `dog` is inherited from the class `animal`. It means that any object of class `dog` gets all the attributes and methods that `animal` class defines. Class `dog` is called `subclass` or `inherited` class while the class `animal` is called `superclass` or `parent` class.

Usually a subclass is used to extend functionality of a class. So class `dog` can modify attributes and/or functionalities of `animal` and/or add its own.

Answer (score 0):

In Python all classes inherit(directly or indirectly) from the `object` class.

as per the code you have posted, the class `dog` inherits from  class `animal`. However it can have more attributes (such as fluffs) and behaviors of its own( e.g. bark) which are not common to all animals

In plain English : `dog` *is-an* `animal`. However `dog` will also have its own set of attributes as well as behaviors.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the first sentence of the answer is not true (unless we're specifically talking about Python 3). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Comment: Also, Python is case sensitive and `object` is spelled with a lowercase `o`.

Comment: @NPE I had editied my answer to say that alll classes directly or indirectly inherit from object. Not sure why the edit did not reflect. I will update once again

Comment: @PrahaladDeshpande This is still not true. Old-style classes in Python 2 don't inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are both classes, and yes dog inherits everything from animal.